# FHIR Managing planned reviews and discharge from a service

Tags: hl7-fhir

My application is an inpatient acute pain service, but similar patterns would exist for other in-hospital and ambulatory service (nutrition, physio and other therapies, social work) - ie any time a service is brought in by the treating team but then manages its own schedule of interaction based on the services' understanding of requirements and ongoing need assessments.

The task from a team/service level is to identify:

- who are are our current patients?
- when do we need to see them again?

So this involves tracking:

- a referral (which would imply a degree of urgency: "please see today/tomorrow")
- individual encounters (which would plan the next visit), and finally
- a "discharge" event ("we're done here, let us know if you need us again")

By itself none of this is awfully complicated (and managed on spreadsheets and back of envelopes all around the world), but struggling to find the right FHIR resources to drop all this into.

It seems that:

- care would be triggered somehow by a [ReferralRequest](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/referralrequest.html)
- each visit should be in an [encounter](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/encounter.html) linked back to the `incomingReferral`
- an [order](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/order.html) would allow tracking the "next visit", although potentially an [appointment](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html) would do that job
- obviously there are lots of [observations](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/observation.html) that the service can record along the way

This leaves these questions:

- What is the role of a [care plan](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/careplan.html) in the mix?
- How to track an episode of care?
- What is the role of a [clinical impression](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/clinicalimpression.html)?
- Via what resource would we make a "summary of care given by the service" available?
- What is the event that triggers the completion of a referral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarePlan is used to share information about what the intended course of care is for a patient - what activities are you going to do, when are you going to do them, how are they going, etc.  If you wanted to track a plan to have 5 encounters over the course of 6 months, maintain a daily pain log, do a set of exercises at least twice a week, etc., CarePlan could be used.  No requirement to use it if not needed though.

EpisodeOfCare is used to link activities related to a single condition that span multiple encounters.  You can link encounters, procedures, etc. to EpisodeOfCare

ClinicalImpression is a new, evolving resource.  Think of it as a specialized type of Observation that's intended to tie together a bunch of other observations and make an overall assessment.

A complete summary of care would typically be represented as a FHIR document - that's a Bundle instance starting with a Composition that would then organize relevant information about the care into a series of sections.  If you don't want the overhead of full document, you can skip the Composition and just have a Bundle containing relevant information.

Completion of Referrals is dependent on business process.  Typically the ReferralRequest instance is owned by the placing/initiating system.  They decide when to mark the request as complete - be that on receiving back a report, knowledge that the transfer of care is done, sufficient elapsed time or other means.  The Order/OrderResponse (to be replaced by Task) can be used to communicate back and forth between placer and filler systems to help coordinate when work is deemed to be complete.

Comment: thanks Lloyd - this is going to take me a while! The ownership by the requesting system is the aspect i was missing I think. I guess ownership by the requesting system is common to the entire order/request family of resources?

Comment: The original order versions of the various "request" resources (ReferralRequest, MedicationOrder, DiagnositcOrder, etc.) are typically owned by the placing system.  (Once a referral is created, it's generally frowned upon for someone other than the author to edit it.)  The Order/OrderResponse or Task resources that manage the fulfillment process can live a variety of places - on the placing system, on the filling system, or on an intermediary system.

Comment: Also, there can be "filler" copies of the various request resources.  For example, MedicationOrder instance can exist to represent the original prescription, the pharmacy-encoded version of the prescription and the instructions to a nursing system for individual scheduled administrations.  (The STU 3 version of the request resources will have attributes that make differentiation of their various uses a bit easier.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the core information is representable by a [ReferralRequest](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/referralrequest.html) that may trigger an [appointment](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html), which becomes an [encounter](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/encounter.html) generating a [Clinical impression](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/clinicalimpression.html) including an [appointment](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html) for the next visit.

## [Clinical impression](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/clinicalimpression.html)

Is often one to one with an encounter. It allows a record of new (and excluded) [conditions](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/condition.html) and also recording a plan which can include an [appointment](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html) action to cover "see again tomorrow"

## [Orders](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/order.html)

Include a [timing](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/datatypes.html#Timing) element so maybe useful for fixed repeating schedules.

## [ReferralRequest](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/referralrequest.html)

ReferralRequest.status has values of (requested | active | cancelled | accepted | rejected | completed) make it a suitable repository to hold the episode of care by the service

## [Episode of care](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/episodeofcare.html)

This resource is similar in many ways to an [encounter](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/encounter.html). Unlike encounters there is no mechanism to nest `Episode of care`s, although each encounter may relate to `0..*` episode of care.s